# Are there any USB battery packs that can provide power while charging?

Tags: usb, power-supply, raspberry-pi

I have an external battery pack, for my phone. But I just bought a Raspberry Pi, and would like to create a UPS - fairly cheaply.

[image]

I tried charging my phone and charging the pack with this one but it stops charging the device when it's receiving power.

Are there any that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Short Answer:* Yes there are power banks that can do that. However, the power bank must support the feature and your phone.A famous brand of power banks can support this feature is **Anker** one type can be found on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00X5RV14Y). There are cheaper ones.

*Output:* However, this is strongly advised! First, being that you power bank will **exponentially** increase in heat depending on your phone. Second, the power bank will from now on take a double amount of time to charge up than not charging your phone at the same time. Third, depending on your phone it will take even longer to charge your phone even once you go back to an adapter and a outlet in the wall. Choose wisely.